# How to increase Azure Data Lake Execution Time Limit

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

The default limit for the jobs in Azure Data Lake is 5 hours. Is there a way to increase this limit?

```
SV_Aggregate[X] ran for 5h 0m 0s, which is over the 5h limit.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no setting can increase this limit. If you want to increase this limit, you need to contact Azure Support to get more throughput. More details, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-performance-tuning-guidance).